# Error:Failure sending mail in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config, sendmail

i have a problem for sending email i enter valid email but when a i click submit button i get this error, Error: Failure sending mail

here is my code(web.Config)

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Soha@sohasys.com">
        <!-- Default Port is [25] -->
        <!-- Specific Port for Gmail is [587] NOT!!! [995]-->
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="mail.Sohasys.com" enableSsl="true" userName="Soha@sohasys.com" password="XXXX" port="587"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and this is my code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage oMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            oMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            oMailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
            oMailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.Never;

            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress oMailAddress = null;

            oMailAddress =
                new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(txtEmail0.Text, ttxtPhone.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            oMailMessage.From = oMailAddress;
            oMailMessage.Sender = oMailAddress;
            oMailMessage.ReplyTo = oMailAddress;

            oMailAddress =
                new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("Soha@sohasys.com", "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            oMailMessage.To.Add(oMailAddress);

            // oMailMessage.CC
            // oMailMessage.Bcc

            oMailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            oMailMessage.Subject = "(From WebSite)" + " : " + txtUsername.Text;

            oMailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            oMailMessage.Body = txtBody.Text;

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient oSmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("Soha@sohasys.com", 587);


              oSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            oSmtpClient.Timeout = 100000;

           // oSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

         //  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

            oSmtpClient.Send(oMailMessage);
            Label5.Visible = true;
            Label5.Text = "Your Email Send SuccesFully.";

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do a `Response.write(ex)` and post the _complete_ error message.

Comment: i had Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message); in my code and this is the complete error i'v got

Comment: you just write the message into the response - I'd recommend 
`Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());` 
to get the stacktrace etc and therefore more inforamation about the error

Comment: I cant give you the entire code instead i can give you some hint. search google for peter bromberg's on asynchronous email. Your code contains lot more unnecessary line of codes. The article will be found on eggheadcafe. I hope it will be a help.

Comment: `ex.Message` is an _incomplete_ error message.

Comment: **WHERE** are you experiencing this? In your local development environment, or your host, or both?

Comment: i'v this error in both side

Comment: @BernhardKircher: thanks,i'v added this line to my code and this is my complete error :http://pastebin.com/ZQT5AyJB

Comment: The details say (**The remote name could not be resolved**):
`Error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'Soha@sohasys.com' at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, ...`
Maybe this is a DNS problem - is the address correct, maybe there are limitations by the mailhost?

Comment: are you sure about the smtp client

Answer (score 1):

please insert this in web.config

```
system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Soha@sohasys.com">
    <!-- Default Port is [25] -->
    <!-- Specific Port for Gmail is [587] NOT!!! [995]-->
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="mail.Sohasys.com" enableSsl="false" userName="Soha@sohasys.com" password="XXXX" port="587"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

set enableSsl to false.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you have wrong settings.

pls try enableSsl="false"

Answer (score 0):

try please instead of the host "mail.Sohasys.com" put the ip address of the smtp in the 
web.config.

and why you mention gmail specific port ... if you use gmail smtp why you using 
"mail.Sohasys.com" use google instead